# Many apps are 'quitting unexpectedly' and showing Crashing on exception: CGSSetSurfaceColorSpace failed with 1000

Tags: macos, crash, apple-silicon, monterey

**System:** M1 Max, Monterey 12.1

**Situation:** Cannot open Anki.app, Calibre epub reader or ColorSync Utility as they all 'quit unexpectedly.' The common error is `CGSSetSurfaceColorSpace failed with 1000` across all three apps, and cannot resolve it. They were all previously working before.

**Steps tried:**

1. Shutting down computer
2. Restarting it
3. Looking online for any other fixes - Some suggest resetting Monitor profile to default, but I have not changed my ICC profile at all (Asus VGA27).

How can I ensure the aforementioned apps open without running encountering the error `CGSSetSurfaceColorSpace failed with 1000`?

**Crash log below:**

````
Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [1347]

Application Specific Information:
Crashing on exception: CGSSetSurfaceColorSpace failed with 1000


Application Specific Backtrace 0:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff806e7a6cb __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007ff806bdcdce objc_exception_throw + 48
2   Foundation                          0x00007ff807c9802c -[NSMutableDictionary(NSMutableDictionary) initWithContentsOfFile:] + 0
3   AppKit                              0x00007ff80a1916cc set_surface_colorspace + 124
4   AppKit                              0x00007ff809dc9e14 NSOpenGLContextUpdateOffScreenViewSurface + 575
5   AppKit                              0x00007ff809a999b3 NSOpenGLContextAttachOffScreenViewSurface + 91
6   AppKit                              0x00007ff809dc948f __27-[NSOpenGLContext setView:]_block_invoke + 432
7   AppKit                              0x00007ff8097a2bf1 NSPerformVisuallyAtomicChange + 132
8   AppKit                              0x00007ff809a99722 -[NSOpenGLContext setView:] + 139
9   libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000011ba1f77d _ZN15QCocoaGLContext11setDrawableEP16QPlatformSurface + 1277
10  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000011ba1f111 _ZN15QCocoaGLContext11makeCurrentEP16QPlatformSurface + 337
11  QtGui                               0x0000000113f8c84c _ZN14QOpenGLContext11makeCurrentEP8QSurface + 172
12  QtGui                               0x0000000114231d6d _ZN21QPlatformBackingStore15composeAndFlushEP7QWindowRK7QRegionRK6QPointP20QPlatformTextureListb + 301
13  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b384c4 _ZN21QWidgetRepaintManager5flushEP7QWidgetRK7QRegionP20QPlatformTextureList + 1028
14  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b3a6ad _ZN21QWidgetRepaintManager5flushEv + 605
15  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b39a58 _ZN21QWidgetRepaintManager13paintAndFlushEv + 4984
16  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b37ea0 _ZN21QWidgetRepaintManager4syncEP7QWidgetRK7QRegion + 672
17  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b875a4 _ZN13QWidgetWindow17handleExposeEventEP12QExposeEvent + 372
18  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b8493b _ZN13QWidgetWindow5eventEP6QEvent + 1067
19  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b2bf5a _ZN19QApplicationPrivate13notify_helperEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 266
20  QtWidgets                           0x0000000115b2d3e6 _ZN12QApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 598
21  QtWidgets.abi3.so                   0x0000000114fdefea _ZN15sipQApplication6notifyEP7QObjectP6QEvent + 234
22  QtCore                              0x0000000110aa09f4 _ZN16QCoreApplication15notifyInternal2EP7QObjectP6QEvent + 212
23  QtGui                               0x0000000113f492c2 _ZN22QGuiApplicationPrivate18processExposeEventEPN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate11ExposeEventE + 306
24  QtGui                               0x0000000113f25cc3 _ZN29QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate23handleWindowSystemEventIN22QWindowSystemInterface19SynchronousDeliveryEEEbPNS_17WindowSystemEventE + 115
25  QtGui                               0x0000000113f2d392 _ZN22QWindowSystemInterface17handleExposeEventINS_19SynchronousDeliveryEEEvP7QWindowRK7QRegion + 178
26  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000011b9e94fc _ZN12QCocoaWindow17handleExposeEventERK7QRegion + 460
27  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000011b9f1b2b -[QNSView(Drawing) displayLayer:] + 907
28  AppKit                              0x00007ff8098af1e6 -[_NSBackingLayer display] + 462
29  AppKit                              0x00007ff80982473d -[_NSViewBackingLayer display] + 554
30  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff80e2e3631 _ZN2CA5Layer17display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 867
31  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff80e433723 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 717
32  QuartzCore                          0x00007ff80e2c5292 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 704
33  AppKit                              0x00007ff8098c0592 __62+[CATransaction(NSCATransaction) NS_setFlushesWithDisplayLink]_block_invoke + 285
34  AppKit                              0x00007ff80a0071d4 ___NSRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler_block_invoke + 41
35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff806dfef98 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff806dfee34 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 543
37  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff806dfe2cb __CFRunLoopRun + 845
38  CoreFoundation                      0x00007ff806dfd8a9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
39  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80fe7f4f1 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
40  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80fe7f247 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 587
41  HIToolbox                           0x00007ff80fe7efe5 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
42  AppKit                              0x00007ff809753b4c _DPSNextEvent + 886
43  AppKit                              0x00007ff8097521b8 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1411
44  AppKit                              0x00007ff8097445a9 -[NSApplication run] + 586
45  libqcocoa.dylib                     0x000000011ba005d3 _ZN21QCocoaEventDispatcher13processEventsE6QFlagsIN10QEventLoop17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 2579
46  QtCore                              0x0000000110a9ca7f _ZN10QEventLoop4execE6QFlagsINS_17ProcessEventsFlagEE + 431
47  QtCore                              0x0000000110aa1002 _ZN16QCoreApplication4execEv + 130
48  QtWidgets.abi3.so                   0x00000001150d0032 _ZL22meth_QApplication_execP7_objectS0_ + 82
49  Python                              0x000000010b6445c2 cfunction_call_varargs + 290
50  Python                              0x000000010b643f85 _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 373
51  Python                              0x000000010b712945 call_function + 533
52  Python                              0x000000010b70f74e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
53  Python                              0x000000010b6448d0 function_code_fastcall + 128
54  Python                              0x000000010b7128ec call_function + 444
55  Python                              0x000000010b70f7e5 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25829
56  Python                              0x000000010b6448d0 function_code_fastcall + 128
57  Python                              0x000000010b7128ec call_function + 444
58  Python                              0x000000010b70f74e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 25678
59  Python                              0x000000010b713734 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 2804
60  Python                              0x000000010b709224 PyEval_EvalCode + 100
61  AnkiMac                             0x000000010232201b AnkiMac + 8219
62  AnkiMac                             0x000000010232241c AnkiMac + 9244
63  AnkiMac                             0x0000000102320bf4 AnkiMac + 3060


Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage
VM - pmap_enter failed with resource shortage


Thread 0 Crashed:: CrBrowserMain Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread```
````

Comment: This looks like something you want to report to Apple via Feedback, if you're able to. It looks like a bug on their side that you're unlikely to be able to work around.

Comment: Sometimes just setting a macOS preference to _something else_, then putting it back to the previous setting will rewrite a corrupted settings file and make things work. I suggest you just try another color profile, then set it back to the one you use now.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Managed to fix this issue. The apps worked when monitor was disconnected. Turns out I had a User ICC profile that I had forgotten about.

**Steps:**

1. Deleted User ICC profile,
2. Restarted computer,
3. Error was removed.

I tried using the old ICC profile again as @IconDaemon suggested, but that profile didn't work for me.